# How to Export a Doc File having name in Hindi Font

Tags: sql, vb.net, export

I am saving a doc file and its name as hindi font in  Sql Server DB. And when displayed in DB Field  its showing correctly. But when i export the text to word document, i'm getting the font like à¤¹à¤¿à¤¨.docx . I am using the following code in vb.net for exporting the file :

```
Dim File As New System.IO.FileInfo(FilePath)  ' File Path Includes the File Name in Hindi Font

Response.Clear()

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + File.Name)

Response.ContentType = "application/doc"

Response.WriteFile(File.FullName)

Response.End()
```

Please tell me how can I export the file having its name in hindi font.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/doc"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
```